# How can I make jQuery open only post links in new tabs in Wordpress for this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code in my header.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
       jQuery("a").click(function(){ 
          jQuery("a").attr("target","_blank"); 
          url=jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
          jQuery(this).attr('href','/te3/out.php?l=click&u=' + escape(url)); 
       }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

And right now it opens all links in new browser tabs. What I would like is to open only the posts. The permalink looks like mywebsite.com/this-is-the post/ if this helps in any way.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: All links are `GET` type.

Comment: could you provide html at least for the posts links? `jQuery("a").attr("target","_blank");` - this part of code opens your link in new window. Maybe you should add some class for your post links and change you js script like this `jQuery(".yourpostlinkclass").click(function(){ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter links with jQuery's `.filter()` method. Just customize the regular expression to fit your actual needs

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery("a")
    .filter(function() {
      var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      // return true if href exists and matches the regular expression
      return href && href.match(/mywebsite\.com\/[\w-]+/);
    })
    .click(function(){ 
      jQuery("a").attr("target","_blank"); 
      url = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
      jQuery(this).attr('href','/te3/out.php?l=click&u=' + escape(url)); 
    }); 
});
```

**Update**

If you want the opposite behavior, you can use `.not()`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery("a")
    .not(function() {
      var href = jQuery(this).attr('href') || '';
      // return true if href exists and matches the regular expression
      return href.match(/mywebsite\.com\/[\w-]+/);
    })
    .click(function(){ 
      jQuery("a").attr("target","_blank"); 
      url = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
      jQuery(this).attr('href','/te3/out.php?l=click&u=' + escape(url)); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm really new to this... If I want to block /page/ , /category/ and /activity/ what should the code look like?  Thank you so much!

Comment: `return href && href.match(/mywebsite\.com\/(page|category|activity)\//);`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! There is only one thing. The code you gave me make ONLY mywebsite.com/page & /category & /activity open in a new tab. I want exactly the opposite. All other links to open in new tabs EXCEPT /page & /category & /activity . Can you please help me do that? Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @Flaviu I added an example of `.not()` to my answer above. You can use the same regular expression from above